# Set mainClass for sbt native packager Universal

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a project that has the following build.sbt:

```
addCommandAlias("package", "dist")

lazy val actual = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(UniversalPlugin, JavaServerAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    name := "DeployerPod",
    mainClass := Some("com.myself.executable.Runner"),
    Compile / mainClass := Some("com.myself.executable.Runner"),
    Compile / run / mainClass := Some("com.myself.utils.Pipeline"),
    Universal / mainClass := Some("com.myself.executable.Runner"),
    Universal / compile / mainClass := Some("com.myself.executable.Runner"),
  )
```

We have a CICD which runs a Dockerfile.
There I have `sbt run` as one of the steps, which will execute `com.myself.utils.Pipeline` class to run a Scala class and do the pre requisites for the pipeline.

As one of the last sbt based steps, I'm also running `sbt package`, which eventually runs an `sbt dist` command. At this point, inside the extracted ZIP's bin folder, I see two BAT files corresponding to the two main classes. Unfortunately I only want the Runner class BAT instead of Pipeline BAT.

For this I tried running `sbt package -main com.myself.executable.Runner` but that failed saying `Not a valid command: -`

Is there a way I can specify the mainClass only for this Universal plugin somehow? Because the way I've tried in my build.sbt doesn't seem to work.